# In Illinois is it against code to have blinds encapsulated in a sliding glass door?

Tags: sliding-glass-door

I was recently getting quotes for windows and a new sliding glass door for the back of the house.  My wife and I like the idea of getting a sliding glass door with the blinds in between the glass panes.  The person quoting us told us that in Illinois its against code to have the blinds in between the glass panes in the back of your house, however perfectly fine in the front of the house.  I have been looking online but can't find anything or anyone talking to this weird regulation.  Does anyone know if this is true or not?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because matters of local code are explicitly off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Ask your Local Authority Having Jurisdiction -- the town inspector. Their opinion is the one that really matters. If they approve it, it passes; if they don't, it doesn't.